# How does the OneNote API generate alt tags for images?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

If alternative text hasn't been added to an image in OneNote, it seems that a machine-generated alt attribute is added. Here's an actual (and rather alarming) example that has appeared in downloaded HTML REST content:

```
<img alt="FucK [T,you credit Matthew Airbnb C: 2016 " ...
```

Is there a way of overriding this machine-generation in the absence of user-entered alternative text?

[EDIT] As requested, here's the image for which the above alt text was generated:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the image that was OCR'd so that we are able to better diagnose the problem with the alt text?

Comment: It would also help to know which language your client/page is configured in.

Comment: English text on the OneNote page: "A : Airbnb = Joe Gebbia #1 credit : Design Week".

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways this can happen. I will report the above, thanks for that feedback.

```
1. The client ran OCR in that image and added this data, offline, in the local machine
2. The server ran OCR in that image and added this data, online
3. The user added this in the client via UI.
```

You can change this programatically by using a PATCH ~/pages/id/content request, like the below:

```
<img alt="Chicharito 14" width="624" height="351" src="https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/resources/0-8120f2b0ec124d64b076876abe6a285e!1-BA887C20112899C4!164/$value" data-src-type="image/jpeg" data-fullres-src="https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/resources/0-8120f2b0ec124d64b076876abe6a285e!1-BA887C20112899C4!164/$value" data-fullres-src-type="image/jpeg" />
```

Or as a user through the OneNote client (right click image -> alt text).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll explore the PATCH option. As for how it happens, it must be by your second suggestion. The HTML text is taken straight from the content pulled down via a PHP script accessing the OneNote REST API, before it even gets to the client in the local machine.